# Differential of a tricky function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a function that I'm strugling to take the differential of.

$$F(t) = F(t-a)G(t).$$
My attempt is the following:
$$ dF(t) = F(t-a)dG(t) + G(t) dF(t-a)) $$

but I have a feeling something is not quite right.

Comment: Could be the extra close parenthesis :). Other than that, it looks good.

Comment: I also tried it. It seems to be correct.